# lista de opciones en formulario con app script

Tags: html, google-hoja-de-cálculo

He generado en una hoja de googlesheets un boton que me trae un formulario html. En el fomrulario hay un campo que debe completarse con un listado de nombres que se genera en otra hoja del mismo documento llamada pacientes. El tema es que no carga las opciones. Le di vueltas pero no logro encontrar el problema.

Por un lado tengo el siguiente codigo que genera la variable que contiene las opciones en formato html.

```
function obtenerPacientes() {  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Pacientes');  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();  var options = '';  data.forEach(function(row) {    options += '<option value="' + row[0] + '">' + row[0] + '</option>';  });  return options;}
```

Y por otro lado dentro de un archivo html tengo el siguiente codigo que deberia cargar la lista de opciones en el formulario.

```
<select name="paciente" required>  <?!= pacienteOptions ?>  </select><br>
```

Pero la lista de opciones me aparece vacia. Alguna idea de donde esta el error?

Gracias!